# TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational when using sympy.solver

Tags: python, scipy

I want to numerically solve the equation

> beta.ppf(x,a,b)-c=0

where a,b,c are known constants. When I tried

```
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import Symbol 
from scipy.stats import beta
x=Symbol('x')
solve(beta.ppf(x,a,b)-c,x)
```

It returned me

> TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational

How can I fix it?

Comment: Is `beta` imported from `scipy.stats`?

Comment: @Stelios Yes, I just forgot to add that line to the post.

Comment: Are you looking for a symbolic or numerical solution? In the first case, the scipy functions cannot help as they necessarily require numerical input (i.e., explicitly assign `a` and `b` numerical values). If you are content with a numerical solution I would suggest using a numerical solver from [scipy.optimize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html).

Comment: @Stelios I am looking for numerical solution because a,b,c are all constants here and I just used symbols to replace them. Doesn't scipy.optimize deal with optimization problems? I just want a solution when the equation equals to 0 here.

Answer (score 1):

[Scipy.optimize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html#root-finding) (check section: "Root finding") provides numerous functions for numerically solving equations.

For the following example, I will use the `newton` function (the other available solvers might be more appropriate for your problem - you should also check them out). I have used arbitrary numerical values for `a`, `b`, and `c`.

```
from scipy.stats import beta
from scipy.optimize import newton

a = 1
b = 2
c = 0.4

def f(x, a, b, c):
    return beta.ppf(x, a, b) - c

newton(f, x0 = 0.2, args = (a,b,c))
```

> `0.6399999999999999`